# php - declare empty array and dynamically add element to that array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to declare an empty array in php and add some elements to that array. I know this is possible to fill array in this way:

```
$list = array("value1", "value2", "value3");
```

But I want to have something like this:

```
$list = array();
$list->add("value1"); //pseudo-code 
// some other program code
$list->add("value2"); //pseudo-code
```

Is there any way for doing that?

Comment: rtm http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) method in PHP:

`array_push($list, "value");`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively:

```
$list = [];

// add values
$list[] = 'foo';

//add more...
$list[] = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Array_Push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Here is an example of it being used:

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
)
```